# SlimDX - Low Resolution in Win7 + DX9 on AMD 6350

Tags: directx, visualization, resolution, directx-9, slimdx

I implemented a Visualisation a few months ago on an old XP Machine with SlimDX and an old Geforce. It worked perfectly. Now i startet the stuff on an new Computer:

Windows7
Intel I7
Amd HD6350

It's still an DirectX 9 Device. But the Resolution now is very low!!! I tested a screenshot in Photoshop. a Pixel in the visualisation consists of 4 Pixels on my Screen. The Control i draw to has 1000 x 1000 Pixels, but Slimdx Stretch 500x500 Pixel to this control... Antialiasing and stuff were on and off - nothing happened.

Anyone an idea? 
:-/

Answer (score 0):

Solution found!!!

Since Win7 the Backbuffer Size has to set manually!